# Change class variables using a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I'm trying to build a simple calculator based on a tutorial I found on the internet (http://www.newthinktank.com/2016/10/kivy-tutorial-3/). I am trying to rebuild his code but using only pure phython, instead of the kv files. This is my code so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Window(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Window,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows=5
        self.padding=10
        self.spacing=10
        self.entry=TextInput(font_size=32)
        self.add_widget(self.entry)
        self.add_widget(Box1())


class Box1(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(orientation='horizontal',**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(CustButton(text='Hi'))


class CustButton(Button):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(CustButton,self).__init__(font_size=32,**kwargs)
    def on_press(self):
        self.entry.text=self.text


class Calculator(App):
    def build(self):
        return Window()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Calculator().run()
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error message: "AttributeError: 'CustButton' object has no attribute 'entry'"

I've tried so many things and can't get this done!! So, how could I change the text of 'Window.entry' w/ the button?

Many thanks from a python newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution - App.get_running_app().root

Use `App.get_running_app().root` to get an instance of the root and access class attributes, methods and wdigets.

## Snippets

```
class CustButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustButton, self).__init__(font_size=32, **kwargs)

    def on_press(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.entry.text = self.text
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Answer (score 0):

Ive added comments in the relative places

```
class Window(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Window,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows=5
        self.padding=10
        self.spacing=10
        self.entry=TextInput(font_size=32)
        self.add_widget(self.entry)
        self.box1 = Box1() # save box1 as an instance attribute
        self.add_widget(self.box1)
        # bind your on_press here ... where you can access the self.entry
        self.box1.button.bind(on_press=self.on_press)
    def on_press(self,target):
        self.entry.text=target.text


class Box1(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(orientation='horizontal',**kwargs)
        self.button = CustButton(text='Hi') # save an instance to our class
        self.add_widget(self.button)


class CustButton(Button):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(CustButton,self).__init__(font_size=32,**kwargs)
    # def on_press(self):
    #    pass # self.entry.text=self.text
```

Comment: Only one more question. Is it normal that you cannot acess properties from another class as in 'Window.entry.text = x'? Do you always must be within the class itself to alter its properties?